# Squid gives always tcp_miss reverse proxy

Tags: squid

I added installed latest squid3 in front of apache as reverse proxy. The problem is that it gives always tcp_miss, in fact I have not yet found a single TCP_HIT message in the log file, and most of the content is static. Relevant config values for cache_dir and refresh_pattern are default ones, directory /var/spool/squid3 exists and has some files/folders. I have 100+G free storage, but reconfigure gives warning "WARNING cache_mem is larger than total disk cache space!", which does not make any sense to me.

I have googled a lot and seen with similar problems, but none of them has helped.

Comment: Can you pastebin your config? /etc/squid3/squid.conf Did you actually create the cache_dir's or were they already there? (squid3 -z etc). Is this still a problem? Do you have any always_direct directives? Have a look at: http://nixforums.org/viewtopic.php?p=927998#927998

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly set `cache_mem` to a value higher than the `cache_dir MBytes` param (the first value after the path string), then you'll get this message:

```
WARNING cache_mem is larger than total disk cache space!
```

Here's what I used, which doesn't throw the warning:

> cache_dir aufs /var/spool/squid 1024 16 256
>   cache_mem 1 GB